# using will_paginate for arrays only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I have a rails app where a user can enter keywords into a search box. From there, I find the id's of those matching keywords, then I do more processing until i arrive at an array of items that fulfill that criteria.

EXAMPLE:

A user searches for people who have a JD degree. I look up the id in the Degrees database, then I look up all companies/firms from my Companies db that employ people who have JDs. Finally i collect the employees with JDs of those companies. Assume that there is no way to start by searching people.

Once I have an array of individuals that meet the requirement, how can I paginate through this array? It seems paginating in the Employee model isn't giving me what i want.

When the user who performs the search hits the 'Next' button, the array of results is gone and i would ideally like to preserve that array appropriately, or get rid of it if the user performs a new search. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

In a file in your `config/initializers`, add this:

`require 'will_paginate/array'`

Then you can use it on arrays:

`my_array.paginate(:page => x, :per_page => y)`

Comment: I guess i forgot to add that in my current situation, when the user who performs the search hits the 'Next' button, the array of results is gone and i would ideally like to preserve that array appropriately, or get rid of it if the user performs a new search. Thoughts?

Comment: Why do you lose it? Aren't you using it in the controller? One option could be saving it to the DB. You could create a new model: `searches`. I've had to do that in a project I worked previously.

Answer (score 2):

The will_paginate gem is definitely a simple solution. The README has a few examples on how to implement it: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate. The :per_page property takes care of retaining the array when you go to the next page of results.